Error configuring Terraform Community Providers
I'm trying to configure a provider to create a Redshift datashare cluster, but I'm encountering some issues.
In the version file, redshift is set to required_providers,
And in the root module, I’ve passed into the child modules with the providers argument.
  providers = {
    redshift = redshift.redshift_cluster
  }

Here’s my code.
What I want to do is to create a cluster that receives a data share.
module "redshift_cluster” {
  source                 = "../../modules/aws_redshift"
  cluster_type           = "single-node"
  …
  name                   = “name-of-the-cluster”
  node_type              = "dc2.large"
  short_env              = local.short_env
  number_of_nodes        = 1
  subnet_ids             = local.private_subnets
  …
  encrypted              = true
  datashare_name = “datashare_name”
  providers = {
    redshift = redshift.redshift_cluster
  }
}

and this is for the response for the terraform plan / terraform validate.
│ Error: Provider type mismatch
│ The local name “redshift.redshift_cluster” in the root module represents provider “techindicium/redshift”, but “redshift” in module.redshift_cluster represents “hashicorp/redshift”.
│
│ Each provider has its own distinct configuration schema and provider types, so this module’s “redshift” can be assigned only a configuration for hashicorp/redshift, which is not required by module. redshift_cluster
Any reply would be thankful!
